# with a standard html form post, no body

Tags: html, forms, http, http-post

I have this form:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">

                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">{{ message }}</label>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" value="joe">
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="field is-grouped">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-link" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-link is-light">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

the oak server is saying i don't have a request body.
chrome dev tools is saying i do not have any Form Data.

Can anyone see why this form would post without form data?.

```
Request URL: https://localhost:8000/signup
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname) attribute for your `<input>` element so itself and the value associated with it can be sent as name-value pairs.

Try defining `<input>` element like this instead:

```html
<input name= "text-input" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" value="joe">
```

so the request would look like this when the input would be, for e.g "myText" (*shortened for demonstration purposes*):

```
Request URL: https://localhost:8000/signup 
Request Method: POST

text-input=myText
```

The [MDN docs provide some insight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) on this too, you might want to visit for clarity.